# Picking out Adverb Phrases from the given sentence

Tags: phrases, adverbials

> He strove **with all his might** **to escape**

According to my Wren and Martin textbook, **with all his might** is an adverb phrase in the given sentence. But what is **to escape**? Is it an adverb phrase as well?

Answer (score 1):

> *He strove with all his might to escape.*

There are no adverbs in your example, so there are no adverb phrases.

"With" is a preposition and "with all his might" is a preposition phrase functioning as a manner **adjunct**.

"To escape" is an infinitival clause functioning as **complement** of "strove".

Comment: This answer, while correct according to its own lights, will doubtless confuse many. The traditional definition 'adverb phrase = phrase acting the same way a single adverb does' is eschewed by CGEL and many other grammarians (and admittedly, since it is also by definition a prepositional phrase {here acting 'adverbially'}, they have a point).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, <strike>"with all his might" is the adverb phrase</strike> (see BillJ's answer instead), while "to escape" is an infinitive verb phrase.

Edit: I should add that the verb 'strive' takes an infinitive, which in this case is 'escape', which may be easier to visualize through bracketing the adverb phrase: "He strove [with all his might] to escape."

You can read more on verbs followed by infinitives [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-infinitive).